# Звонилка  без intent

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.
Как позвонить из приложения ?  не вызвать с помощью intent встроенную звонилку а реализовать свою.

Answer (score 1):

к сожалению такого способа нет. в любом случае надо использовать Intent.ACTION_CALL.

Comment: а как можно определить состояние звонка? -  например занято, недоступен, снял трубку